# Install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 over Serial Console

Tags: system-installation, serial-port

I have a device that I need to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 on, but the device only has a Serial Console port, USB ports, and LAN ports. I've looked around on here and on Google but can't find a sufficient answer. When I connect over serial to my desktop (running ubuntu) I can get into the bootloader but once it boots I don't get anything on the screen. AFAIK this is because serial consoles are for text, not graphics, but I was told to make this happen so I'm trying to make it happen. I have an Ubuntu ISO on a USB that's plugged into the target device, but no idea where to go from here.

Comment: If it is an enterprise server, like a Dell PowerEdge, using the iDRAC Virtual Console might work (for Dell). HP has a simaler thing

Comment: @cocomac it's a Protectli FW4B (without any HDMI ports)

Comment: It's unclear if you want to display a Desktop Environment over the serial connection, or if this install is intended for remote desktop connections (like x2go or rdp or vnc).